Given the function values at vertices, how do I approximate an integral of function over a triangle/quadrilateral, consistently?
Consider following triangle PQS:

I have a function $f(\vec{r})$, which I want to integrate over this triangle. But I only know the function value at its vertices and cannot evaluate it elsewhere. A natural way of doing this seems to be
$$
I = \int_{\Delta PQS} dA f(\vec{r})
\\\approx \frac{A}{3} (f(P)+ f(Q) + f(S))
$$
Similarly, if I have a square, PQRS, in a 2-D plane:

and if I were to approximate the integral in a similar manner, my intuition says,
$$
I = \int_{\square PQRS} dA f(\vec{r})
\\\approx \frac{A}{4} (f(P)+ f(Q) + f(R)+ f(S))
$$
However, if I subdivide this squade into two triangles:

I should expect, from previous triangle formula, the integral to be
$$
I = \int_{\square PQRS} dA f(\vec{r})
\\\approx \frac{A}{6} (f(P)+ 2f(Q) + f(R)+ 2f(S))
$$
which favors points $Q$ and $S$ despite the symmetry of the square.
I believe the core of issue here is that both the triangle and quadrilateral formulae do not account for the geometrical quantities of each point when assuming their weight. For instance, if P and R had twice the weight od the Q and S in triangle formula for some reason, subdivision should be consistent. One way I could think of to justify this is that the weight of each point being proportional to the angle at each point, but I couldn't find anything close.
Could someone share anything relevant to this topic? I am not sure where to begin with.

